# Can't post using useEffect and axios

Tags: javascript, react-native

I'm trying to POST new users using useEffect(). I was able to do using componentDidMount.
My hooks are working okay (outside the useEffect), but when It comes to the api.post. The code doesn't post anything. I tried to throw the hook inside the useEffect() but says("Invalid Hook call"). I used some hooks to handle the inputs and when I press a button change the state of my hook normally, but the api doesn't post to my DB.
The code enters in the useEffect() but doesn't execute the api.post. Anyone can help me on this? I'm hunting this bug for 2 days. Here is my code:

```
    //Hooks
    const [name, setUserName] = useState('');
    const [userEmail, setEmail] = useState('');
    const [userPassword, setPassword] = useState('');
    const [avatar, setAvatar] = useState('');

    const [enteredUserName, setEnteredUserName] = useState('');
    const [enteredEmail, setEnteredEmail] = useState('');
    const [enteredPassword, setEnteredPassword] = useState('')

    useEffect((userName, email, password) => {
        api.post('users/signup', {userName: name , email: userEmail, password: userPassword}).then(data => {
            navigation.navigate('Home');
        }).catch(err => {
            if (err === true) {
                Alert.alert('Invalid Credentials')
            }
        }, []);
    })
    const userNameInputHandler = (enteredText) => {
        setEnteredUserName(enteredText)
    };
    
    const userEmailInputHandler = (enteredText) => {
        setEnteredEmail(enteredText);
    };

    const userPasswordHandler = (enteredText) => {
        setEnteredPassword(enteredText);
    };

    const handler = () => {
        setUserName(currentUserNames => [...currentUserNames, enteredUserName]);
        setEmail(currentEmails => [...currentEmails, enteredEmail]);
        setPassword(currentPasswords => [...currentPasswords, enteredPassword]); 
    };
```

The handler is my Register button. When pressed call the handler().

Answer (score 0):

```
useEffect is calling once because you passes [] at the end. i.e

useEffect(()=>{},[]);

if you want to execute useEffect on change of something then pass that as dependency i.e []
```

Answer (score 0):

if you're calling this function on button press, then it must be outside of useEffect.
also when you want to use hooks with an async function, you have to declare it outside of the hook and then calling it inside the hook; like:

`
const login = async () => {};

useEffect(login(),[]);

`

Answer (score 0):

You may create the lifeCycle hook **useComponentDidMount.js**

```
export const useComponentDidMount = (cb) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    cb();
  }, []);
};
```

and use it like

```
useComponentDidMount(() => {
  axios.fetch(...)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

useEffect have any arguments, please remove **userName, email, password**
and use like

useEffect(() => {
api.post('users/signup', {userName: name , email: userEmail, password: userPassword}).then(data => {
navigation.navigate('Home');
}).catch(err => {
if (err === true) {
Alert.alert('Invalid Credentials')
}
}, []);
})